# Get source code of website into a string

Tags: vb.net, geckofx

I don't get how to get the source code of a website in GeckoFX into a string.

When I use

```
GeckoWebBrowser1.ViewSource("www.google.de")
```

a new window will open with the source code inside, nice to see, but no chance to load it into a string.

When I use

```
GeckoWebBrowser1.Navigate("view-source:www.google.de")
```

the source code is shown in the GeckoFX Browser, but I also did not know, how to get it into a string.

I'm sure the solution is simple, but I don't see it. So it would be great if anybody could help me out of this struggle.

Answer (score 0):

There are more than a few ways per say to retrieve the websites `html`. As mentioned already you can use the `WebClient` class to retrieve it or in your case using `GeckoFX`. In order to get the internal `html` you need to dig into the `DocumentElement` and then into `GeckoHtmlElement`...

```
 Dim element As GeckoHtmlElement = Nothing
 Dim geckoDomElement = GeckoWebBrowser1.Document.DocumentElement
 If TypeOf geckoDomElement Is GeckoHtmlElement Then
    element = DirectCast(geckoDomElement, GeckoHtmlElement)
    If element IsNot Nothing AndAlso element.InnerHtml IsNot Nothing Then
      Dim innerHtml = element.InnerHtml 'this is the source of the webpage. Here do what you want with the html...          
    End If
 End If
```